# Comparing BigDecimal to 0 in JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

Excuse the basic question, I'm crash-coursing myself on Java/JSTL to fix an issue for a client and have not been able to quickly find the answer to something I'm dealing with....

I have a JSP page which uses the `<c:if>` tag to compare a variable to the constant value of `0`. This is always returning `False` for me. I.e.

```
<c:set var="total" value="0" />
<c:forEach items="${parentItem.children}" var="child">
    <c:set var="total" value="${total+child.revenue}" />
    <c:if test="${total == 0}">
        It is zero.
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

From my understanding, I have to explicitly compare like-types, however when attempting to do something like this, I get an error:

```
<c:if test="${total.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0}">
    -
</c:if>
```

The error is: `The function compareTo must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified`.

I'm using JSTL 1.2.

Comment: Have you studied the other [similar Questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=function+compareTo+must+be+used+with+a+prefix+when+a+default+namespace+is+not+specified.++&t=ffip&ia=qa)?

Comment: @BasilBourque, Extensively. None of the examples work for me without giving me the exception message that I've listed.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but does not feel right:

```
<c:if test="${total eq '0.0'}">
```